# How to find the average pairwise distance in G for a "flower" graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

[image]

I need to know how to compute the sum of the distances between all pairs of “pedal” nodes of the flower graph. And the sum of the distances between all pairs of “stalk” nodes

I know that the average pairwise distance =∑(v1,v2)∈V distance(v1,v2)/(n choose 2), but I dont know how to compute it for this graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In total, you have $n^2+n$ nodes in your graph. We can first calculate the distances between various pairs of nodes:

- the distance from $x_i$ to $x_j$ is equal to $2$ for any $i \neq j$,
- the distance from $x_i$ to $y_j$ is equal to $j$ for any $i, j$,
- the distance from $y_i$ to $y_j$ is equal to $|i-j|$ for any $i, j$.

Typically we don't calculate the distance from a node to itself when calculating the average distance, so our actual formula is:
$$
\bar{d}_G = \frac{1}{\binom{n^2+n}{2}}\sum_{i \neq j \in \{x_1, \dots, x_{n^2}, y_1, \dots, y_n\}} d(i, j)
$$
We can divide the above sum into three cases corresponding to the three enumerated dots above.
First case, when both vertices are type $x$:
$$\bar{d}_1 = \frac{1}{\binom{n^2}{2}}\sum_{i \neq j \in \{x_1, \dots, x_n^2\}}d(i, j) = \frac{1}{\binom{n^2}{2}}\binom{n^2}{2}\cdot 2 = 2$$
The second case, when one vertex is type $x$ and the second vertex is type $y$:
$$
\bar{d}_2 = \frac{1}{n^2\cdot n}\sum_{i \in \{x_1, \dots, x_{n^2}\}, j \in \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}} d(i, j) = \frac{1}{n^3}(n^2 \cdot 1 + n^2\cdot 2 + \dots n^2 \cdot n )= \frac{1}{n^3} n^2 \cdot (1 + 2 + \dots + n) = \frac{n+1}{2}
$$

Finally, the third case, when both vertices are of $y$ type. Subgraph induced on the vertices of type $y$ is a path on $n$ vertices. Notice that we have $n-1$ pairs of vertices being in distance $1$ from each other, $n-2$ pairs of vertices being in distance $2$ from each other, and so on. So,
$$
\bar{d}_3 = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}} (1\cdot (n-1) + 2\cdot (n-2) + 3\cdot (n-3) + \dots + (n-1) \cdot 1) = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} i\cdot (n-i) = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{2}} \frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6} = \frac{n+1}{3}
$$

We can now calculate $\bar{d}_G$ as a weighted average of our partial results:
$$
\bar{d}_G = \frac{\binom{n^2}{2}\cdot 2 + n^3 \cdot \frac{n+1}{2} + \binom{n}{2}\frac{n+1}{3}}{\binom{n^2+n}{2}} = \frac{9n^2-5n-1}{3(n^2+n-1)}
$$

Comment: Why is it that the distance for xi to xj is equal to 2 for any i≠j?

Comment: Sorry one more question, in that case what would be the asymptotic bound of the sum of the distances between all pairs of “pedal” nodes, and the asymptotic bound for  the sum of the distances between all pairs of “stalk” nodes?

Comment: The shortest path between any $x_i, x_j$ nodes is via $y_1$. So, the distance between any such vertices is equal to $2$. The sum of distance between petal nodes is exactly $2\binom{n^2}{2}$ and the sum of distances between stalk nodes is exactly $\binom{n}{2} \frac{n+1}{3}$, so I don't see why you need asymptotic bounds.

Comment: Oh okay got it. I need the asymptotic bound for the requirements of the question. Is the first one  xi to xj O(n^4) and from yi to yj is O(n^3)?

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: Please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if you are satisfied with my explanation.

Comment: One last question, why is it in the third case that we are using the reciprocal of the n chose 2 combination?

Comment: There are $n$ stalk vertices, so there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs. We divide by the number of pairs to obtain average distance. "Average distance" times "number of pairs" equals "sum of distances".